# Loop trough XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops, parsing

I am trying to Loop trough an XML Output I got from an API call.
The Structure of the XML looks like the following:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <products>
  <product>
   <id>97</id>
   <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
   <id_supplier>0</id_supplier>
   <width>0.000000</width>
   <height>0.000000</height>
   <depth>0.000000</depth>
   <weight>1.127272</weight>
   <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
   <on_sale>0</on_sale>
   <online_only>0</online_only>
   <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
   <price>37.000000</price>
  </product>
  <product>...</product>
  <product>...</product>
  <product>...</product>
  <product>...</product>
 </products>
</prestashop>
```

I would like to loop trough all the products and get for example the price.
I already tried separate ways such like:

```
 $opt = array(
       'resource' => 'products',
       'display'  => 'full',
       'filter[id]' => $_GET['id'],
       'postXml' => 'asXML'
    );

    $xml = $webService->get($opt); // getting the xml data as shown above
    

foreach ($xml->products->product as $p) {
    echo $p->attributes()->price;
}
```

But the result is not going to show anything ...
I would be glad if you could help me out and maybe have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`price` isn't an attribute of `<product>`, it's a child node. So if, for example you want to extract the price (that is, the string value of the `price` element) you can do something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$products = $xpath->query("//product");
foreach ($products as $prod)
{   
   foreach ($xpath->query('.//price',$prod) as $price) {
        echo ($price->textContent)."\n";
 
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately it is not working. I got no Output out of this..

Comment: @LiamBonactarian  It works with the sample xml in your question; your actual xml may be significantly different from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer was on the right track, but didn't actually show how to loop over the XML object.

```
<?php
$myXMLData = '<prestashop>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>97</id>
            <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
            <id_supplier>0</id_supplier>
            <width>0.000000</width>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <depth>0.000000</depth>
            <weight>1.127272</weight>
            <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
            <on_sale>0</on_sale>
            <online_only>0</online_only>
            <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
            <price>37.000000</price>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>98</id>
            <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
            <id_supplier>0</id_supplier>
            <width>0.000000</width>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <depth>0.000000</depth>
            <weight>1.127272</weight>
            <quantity_discount>0</quantity_discount>
            <on_sale>0</on_sale>
            <online_only>0</online_only>
            <minimal_quantity>1</minimal_quantity>
            <price>37.000000</price>
        </product>
    </products>
</prestashop>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->products->product as $product){
    print_r($product->id);
    /*You can access all of your product object properties here.*/
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I do not understand the use of print_r($product->id)

Comment: If you run this code in a command line environment print_r is a PHP function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php that outputs the variable to screen. You could also use var_dump($product); to output the entire product variable https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately it does not give me any output.

Comment: You can try creating a new PHP file. I tested it and there is no problem. His output is as follows.
```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 97
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 98
)

```